# How do I "pin" the copying file(s) progress dialog in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows 8, I loved how you could "pin" the dialog that showed the graph of copy speed while a long file copy operation (using Windows Explorer) was occurring.  If you left the machine and came back later, you could see that the copy operation had completed and have confidence it did not abort early due to an error or whatever.

Windows 10 has a very similar dialog, but the ability to "pin" it is gone, once the copy operation is complete the dialog is automatically closed.

Is there a registry setting or some other way to restore the ability to pin these dialogs or prevent them from automatically closing?

Comment: @davidpostill thanks for correcting my embarrassing typo